# Custom TextView and ListView versus a GridView suggestions

Tags: android

I have an application that is a task management application.  The application uses tabs to separate tasks, calendar, and notes functionality.  The primary view by the user is a Task view which is currently implemented as a List with a ListAdaptor class to put all the widgets together in a single row.

Each row contains the following items:

- Spinner to allow use to select the priority for a task (i.e. A1, A2.. B1.. D4)
- TextView to enter a description of the tasks
- CheckBox for the user to indicate if the task is completed
- TextView for an optional date field
- Button to attach a note to the task

On a phone the above items take up too much room.  For example, the spinner component takes up space to display the value as well as the drop down menu.  Checkbox and button are also too big for the list view on a device like a phone.

Here are my questions:

1. Custom Spinner.  What I really need in the application is a simple text field that shows the users priority for the task with the ability to click on the text and select from options similar to a spinner component.  Should I extend a TextView component to do that or is it possible to modify the look of the Spinner to function like a spinner but display like a text field?
2. Shrinking components.  Is it possible to shrink the default Android components like the spinner, checkbox, and button to better fit in a row with limited size?  Do I have to extend components to do this or are their attributes that can do this easier?
3. Lastly, I have implemented this functionality using a ListView.  Would it be easier to control the cells in each row using a GridView instead of a ListView?  What are the benefits and disadvantages to using a GridView versus a ListView?

Thanks in advance for an advice on the above questions.

Brett

Answer (score 0):

1. Why don't you add a click listener to your TextView and show for example a context menu with all your items when TextView is clicked.
2. You may limit the size of the components by setting their width/height to a desired value. Set text size, paddings and margins of the components to a minimum value as well. Note that components' background may also define paddings, so define your own background drawable with no paddings.
3. Not many differences. You will provide ListAdapter for both. I would say that GridView is likely used for galleries, ListView being used for tasks like your. ListView also gives you more control over its items.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I'll adding a click listener to TextView with a menu.  All the answers were very helpful.